# Create a list of Spatial Polygons based on a list of shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sp

I have a list of Shapefiles `list_shp_Tanzania` with 61 shapefiles and each shapefiles contains several polygons. I want to create a Spatial Polygons list out of this shapefile list. Here is the structure of a polygon in a shapefile.

```
  .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 39 -11
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 2.65e-05
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:67, 1:2] 39 39 39 39 39 ..
```

Can somebody help me out with it?

Comment: I have done a `dput` for the dataset

Comment: `dput` doesn't work for S4 objects, sorry.

Comment: Ok. But would have any idea on how I could fix my issue?

Comment: You don't have a list of shapefiles, you have a list of SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. Did you read them in from 61 shapefiles using `readOGR` or `readShapeSpatial`?

Comment: I managed to get a list of SpatialPolygons by using this command line `list_sp_Tanzania<-lapply(list_shp_Tanzania, function (x) SpatialPolygons(x@polygons))  `. But now I want to use this `Spatial polygons` list to create `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` from another list of dataframe. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: The function `sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(your.sp.polygons, your.df)` may help.